# Relationship between schemes and algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I've just begun to learn algebraic geometry, and to my understanding Grothendieck's revolutionary idea was to define a generalization for algebraic varieties (affine, projective, quasi-affine & quasi-projective) that eliminated restrictions imposed by working over algebraically closed fields, by instead working over general commutative rings. This lead to modern algebraic geometry and scheme theory.

I've got some questions regarding things that I've not yet grasped.

1. Why are there 3 types of varieties and what is the relationship between them?
2. If affine, quasi-affine and projective varieties are all special cases of quasi-projective varieties, then why not just use them in the first place?
3. If schemes are a generalization of algebraic varieties, then how are affine, projective, quasi-affine & quasi-projective varieties defined in terms of schemes?

Comment: 1. What is not clear from the definition? In geometry, one studies e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$ but very often it is useful to study its projective counterpart $\mathbb{R} P^n$. It's similar for varieties. And quasi-... just takes open subspaces.

Comment: 2. Integers, rational numbers and real numbers are all just special cases of complex numbers, so why not just use complex numbers? We need a name for all of these important special cases.

Comment: 3. I think you can find these definitions on your own.

Comment: Regarding (3), the only definition I've been able to find in the literature is that varieties over an algebraically closed field k are integral separated schemes of finite type over k. But what kind of variety is being referenced in that definition?

Comment: @LeonardoLovera All kinds of varieties fall under that definition; neither integrality nor finite type-ness over $k$ have anything to do with being (quasi-)affine or (quasi-)projectiv, while separatedness is required for all of them.